# Regularity of a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to know, in which cases i can say that a tridiagonal matrix is regular, i.e. it has an inverse?
I know that it is not strong diagonal dominant and in think i have to use that $A$ is regular if $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution $x=0$. But is this the right way and does it hold only if i have a row in which the strong diagonal dominance is given?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you know about your matrix?

Comment: I have 2 options: The first is the matrix with value 2 in diagonal and -1 on the left and right of this diagonal. The second option is that i have only 2 and -1 in the first (and last) row instead of -1 2 -1.

Comment: But then the first is not tridiagonal? The second is diagonally dominant (the condition is diagonal $\geq$ sum of the rest of the row, and strict inequality at least once), thus regular. The first is not regular: try multiplying with (1 1 ... 1)

Comment: And why is the second regular?

Comment: Because here "[diagonal dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) + strictly on at least one line" => "irreducibly diagonally dominant matrix" => regular. Alternately, you can compute explicitly the determinant by a recurrence formula (recurrence of order 2 on the matrix size).

Comment: Thank you so far :-) Where can I find the result that a irreducibly diagonally dominant matrix is regular? I need to understand this.

Comment: I'll have a look tonight (it's midday here). I would expect Golub & Van Loan to have this, or maybe Bulirsch & Stoer or Varga (*"Matrix Iterative Analysis"*, there is material about diagonally dominant matrices in first chapter). IIRW, there is a proof involving [Gershgorin discs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

Comment: One method I use to show a matrix is regular is to show it is positive definite.  This works if the matrix is symmetric.  I think it will work with your particular matrix.